# Will s3 creates objects itself when we save a file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a dataframe and selected some columns say col1col2 and col3 using df.select().
`df1=df.select(col1,col2,col3)`

I am writing this into a parquet file and saving it to s3.

```
df1.write.partitionBy("col1").format("parquet").save('s3a://myBucket/fol1/subfolder')
```

currently there is no location like 's3a://myBucket/fol1/subfolder' in my s3. Only thing I have is 's3a:myBucket'. My question as  there are no objects named fol1 and subfolder.Will It create objects itself and save the file? or the code will fail?

Comment: Hello! Please provide more details about what you're doing

Comment: @victor please check the edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking if `save('s3a://myBucket/fol1/subfolder')` will create the `fol1/subfolder` structure in S3, and if it doesn't, do you need to.

The bottom line is that you don't need to worry about creating the intermediate folder structure because Hadoop FS API creates it for you, as needed.

@SteveLoughran's answer provides much more detail and deserves to be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @jarmod I used partitionBy('col1').Can you tell me how the files are stored in s3 based on the above code.Lets say col1 is dates of type string. Will the file be saved in this way '20180829.parquet' inside s3a://myBucket/fol1/subfolder/?If I want it this way what should be the code? '2018829_myfile.parquet'

Comment: Not sure but I'd expect it to create s3://myBucket/fol1/subfolder/col1=xyz/file.parquet or similar, partitioned on the various col1 values, but please test it.

Comment: not quite: the opening mkdirs() of the job will create the dir marker, but the first mkdirs of a subdir or written file underneath will delete it. Inefficient but it helps meet the expectations of code written for "real" filesystems.

Comment: @SteveLoughran that makes a lot of sense, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Although S3 is an object store, Spark, Hive &c all pretend its a filesystem & use the Hadoop filesystem API.

Some early actions of a spark save() are

1. call `FileSystem.exists(dest)` & fail if there's something there (unless you have enabled appending to existing data)
2. call `FileSystem.mkdir(dest)`.
3. set up some `_temporary` dir underneath for the job, renaming things into place when the job is committed.

Action #2 triggers a scan for any entry in the path `/a/b/c/dest` being a file (Failure), creates an empty directory marker object `/a/b/c/dest/`. That marker will be deleted as soon as a child directory (i.e `_temporary`) is created.

At the end of the job then, there won't be any parent marker entries, but they go in there just to keep quiet all those bits of code which expect that after a `mkdirs()` call that the created directory exists.

Finally, be advised: the whole commit-by-rename mechanism is broken when it comes to S3 as it is (a) slow and (b) at risk of losing data due to directory listing consistency. You need a consistent listing layer (EMR: Consistent S3, Apache Hadoop: S3Guard, Databricks: something also DynamoDB based), and, for maximum performance atop Apache Hadoop 3.1, switch to a specific zero-rename S3A committer.